# unable to pass a variable in pyrebase

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pyrebase

I am trying to read data from the firebase real-time db using pyrebase. when attempting to pass a variable instead of a string, I don't get a value. When a string is passed the value is successfully retrieved.

**Works**

```
def calculate_score(request,*args, **kwargs):    
    account_type = request.POST.get('atype', False)
    db_target = database.child('PMS').child('Indie').child('Cornerstone').get().val()
```

Doesn't work:

```
def calculate_score(request,*args, **kwargs):    
    account_type = request.POST.get('atype', False)
    db_target = database.child('PMS').child('Indie').child(account_type).get().val()
```

running `request.POST.get('atype', False)` I see that it is a string.

ie. Also tried str(account_type) and passing as a dict

Answer (score 1):

The `child()` function only accepts a string, but that can be either a literal string (like in your first snippet) or a string variable. If the second snippet doesn't work, it's most likely that the `account_type` is not a string.

I'm not a Python expert, but you'll want to see what type `request.POST.get('atype', False)` returns and convert that to a string of needed.